# How to rename the output file with variable name?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, rename, batch-rename

I want to run a script 4000 time, every time it produces an output file named min1.gro. Each time it will replace the previous version. I want to name the output with a different name for the 4000 output so that I can access later any one specifically. So how can I automate the naming process ?

Part of my script is as below:

```
    va3=$(grep -o -i G8LE C60_GRM_box.gro | wc -l)
    export va4=$(expr $va3 / 60)

    insert-molecules -ci C60.gro -nmol 1  -f C60_GRM_box.gro -o C60_GRM_box.gro


    grompp -f minim.mdp -c C60_GRM_box.gro -r C60_GRM_box.gro -p C60_GRM_box.top -o min1.tpr -maxwarn 1

    mdrun -v -deffnm min1

    fi
```

now I have an output named min1.gro I want to rename it differently from 1 to 4000 is possible, as I will run the below command to run the above script 4000 time.

```
   for i in {1..4000}; do bash Simulation.sh; done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
   for i in {1..4000}; do bash Simulation.sh; mv min1.gro min1_${i}.gro; done
```

for example.